# What kind of SPN is required to delegate client credentials to a SMB Share?

Tags: authentication, kerberos, server-message-block, sql-server-2008-r2, delegation

I'm trying to [delegate KERBEROS authentication from an SQL Server to a file server over OLEDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134515/what-sort-of-spn-ad-computer-delegation-do-you-need-for-delegation-of-credenti).

Is there a particular Service Principle Name that is used to delegate credentials from an SQL Server to a file server?

For instance, if I run a SQL Server instance, I have to make a domain username for it to run on...and I have to create a SPN for example:

`setspn -S MSSQLSvc/someserver.example.org:50000 example\SQL_srv_account
setspn -S MSSQLSvc/someserver:50000 example\SQL_srv_account`

So what would I set for the `LanmanServer` / `Server`service that runs SMB?

I guess my question is, if my SMB server runs on port 445, then what should my command look like for setting the SPN?

`setspn -S <what-goes-here?>/someotherserver.example:445 example\SMB_srv_account
setspn -S <what-goes-here?>/someotherserver:445 example\SMB_srv_account`

`<what-goes-here?>` wouldn't be `cifs` [would it](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731241.aspx#BKMK_Rem)?

P.S. This is a question with a bit of overlap between serverfault and the dba stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is correct, it would be 'cifs'.